# Remove the gnu style indentation from struct functions in c++

Tags: emacs, indentation

I am using emacs. I have set the  indentation style as "linux", but for functions in structm somehow the indentation style turns out to be gnu. How do I remove it?

What I have is this:

```
struct Graph{
    vector<lld> *adj;
    lld V;
    Graph(lld V_)
        {
            V=V_;
            adj=new vector<lld>[V+1];
        }

}
```

What I want is this:

```
struct Graph{
    vector<lld> *adj;
    lld V;
    Graph(lld V_)
    {
            V=V_;
            adj=new vector<lld>[V+1];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to achieve that:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda () (c-set-offset 'inline-open 0)))
```